# Shell script to get the OS version

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that will show me the OS version. I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.

How can i write a shell script that will show me the OS version?

Comment: Do you care about platforms/distributions other than Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by "OS version"? The output of `lsb_release` is probably more or less what you want.

Comment: No i dont care about other platforms @AndrewMarshall

Comment: The current OS version running. I need to show that. @tripleee

Comment: Showing your hello world program is completely pointless.

Comment: The concept is not well-defined. The kernel has a version and the distro has a version but neither of these is stricly speaking an "OS version".  But the distro and its version would probably satisfy your need to idenify the "OS version".

Comment: StackOverflow doesnt let me post question if i dont put some codes. Thats why. Sorry for being pointless @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Yes, the kernel version i mean. Sorry,my bad. For being unclear. @tripleee

Comment: @HasibHasan There are only about 30 *million* results if you Google for [`linux get kernel version`](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+get+kernel+version). What you're looking for is `uname -r`.

Comment: This question have already many answers in http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`lsb_release`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lsb_release.1.html):

```
$ lsb_release -sr
12.04
```

See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lsb_release.1.html) for all available options. Note that not all platforms or Linux distributions have `lsb_release`.

Comment: Thats the terminal command. I want my program to have it. An d when i execute my program (example, my_program) using the "./my_program" in the terminal it will show the OS version, the lsb_release.

Comment: @HasibHasan So… put the command in a script instead of just running it.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the output of `uname`:

`#!/bin/bash
uname -s`

and Bob's your uncle. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanx hd1. It shows the name of the OS "Linux". how do i get the kernel version? 14.04?

Comment: 14.04 is not a kernel version @HasibHasan, but you can try uname -v or as the other answer suggests, you can use lsb-release on Linux to get that number.